# destructure vector by index

Tags: clojure, destructuring

I'd like to know if there is a way to destructure a vector by index. Basically, a shorthand that would allow me to avoid:

```
(defn f [v]
    (let [x (nth v 4)
          y (nth v 5)]
        (println x y)))
```

This is my basic problem:

```
user=> (defn f [{x 4 y 5}] (println x y))
#'user/f
user=> (f [0 1 2 3 4 5 6])
4 5
nil
user=> (f (apply vector (range 10)))
4 5
nil
user=> (f (range 10))
5 nil
nil
user=>
```

Comment: Your question is rather significantly changed by the edit. In any case, `(range 10)` is a lazy seq, thus not associative, thus this won't work. Or rather, works differently. See comments on my answer for more details.

Comment: So, the answer to your original question about destructuring vector by index is that yes, you can do it; the answer to the new question about destructuring seqs by index is that you can't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Answer to the original question about destructuring vectors:

Vectors are associative, so you can use associative destructuring:

```
(let [{x 4 y 5} [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]]
  [x y])
;= [4 5]
```

Responding to the comment below, this works everywhere any destructuring forms work, including in `fn` parameter lists:

```
((fn [{x 4 y 5}] [x y]) [0 1 2 3 4 5 6])
;= [4 5]
```

#### Answer to the new question about destructuring seqs:

If you pass a seq to a function defined as above in place of a vector, the rule for associative destructuring of seqs will be applied. Namely, the seq will first be poured into a hash map -- `(range 10)` becomes `{0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}` at this stage -- and then this hash map will be destructured as a map.

There is no way of destructuring seqs by index. This is by design, as seqs are not meant for applications requiring fast random access.

Comment: I want the destructuring in the function argument list, so I can avoid a let.

Comment: I added more info to my question, which is what prompted my question in the first place; which is that it only works when the argument is a vector. If it's a list, it suddenly doesn't work.

Comment: Nothing sudden about it, lists are not associative and map destructuring operates on them in a different manner. Specifically, they (and other seq types) are first poured into a new hash map, which is then used in the destructuring operations.

Comment: The result here is that `(range 10)` is first transformed to `{0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}` and it is this map that is later destructured. Note that it does not have a key of `5` (the `5` is the value at key `4`).

Comment: Edited all this into the answer.

Comment: You're right, I guess the thing I'm complaining about is that there's no concise way to make this work generally if you don't know or don't control all the callers.

Comment: Generally Clojure's sugar doesn't support data structures which are not a good fit for the job at hand, like seqs in the case of random access. This may be inconvenient at times, but I think the design principle is sound. Having said that, if you are willing to accept seqs from your callers, you can write your own function like `(fn get-by-indices [is xs] (if (associative? xs) #_"vector and map case" (mapv #(get xs %) is) #_"seq case" (loop [...] ...)))` where the `loop` gets the values; then you can just use `[x y]`-style destructuring on the vectors it returns.